# How to set Vue Css variable on background Image

Tags: vuejs3

`     Here is my state
const icon = ref('image.jpg')

```
 <style scoped>
 background-image: url(icon);
 </style>

 This approach is not working please advise how to go about it

 background-image: url(icon);

 This approach is not working please advise how to go about it`
```

Comment: I answered and understood what you meant but I should inform you your style is non-existent you should declare that property inside an element or class, I get anyway the question but you should try to be as clear as possible when asking something online

Answer (score 0):

You should declare **url** inside the script and call it within the template:

```
<script setup>
const url = ref('yourUrl');
</script>
<template>

<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${url})` }">
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: i dont not want to access the variable inside a template. I want to bind the state inside CSS style Sheet examples.. const color = ref('red') then inside stylesheet background-color: v-bind(color). So how do I do background-image: url('image.jpg')

Comment: I really think this is not possible to achieve in vue 3 and any other js framework at the moment, you can do dynamic style and class bindings in the template with css variable if you really want to create a dynamic situation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Vue.js variable in a CSS property,One Way is you should bind the style dynamically using :style directive. For example:

```
<template>
  <div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${icon})` }">
    <!-- Your content goes here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const icon = ref('image.jpg');

    // You can update the icon value as needed
    // icon.value = 'new-image.jpg';

    return { icon };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Your additional styles go here */
</style>
```

Comment: i dont not want to access the variable inside a template. I want to bind the state inside CSS style Sheet examples.. const color = ref('red') then inside stylesheet background-color: v-bind(color). So how do I do background-image: url('image.jpg')...background-image: v-bind(ref) is not working